# Как изменить порядок последовательности элементов в navbar toggler?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: На большом экране]
Как изменить последовательность элементов на маленьких брейкпойнтах?
Т.е. например, я хочу что бы при разворачивании тогглера у меня поиск был самый первый, а все остальные пункты ниже.
[image: На маленьком экране]

Comment: могу javascript-ом написать

Comment: Исходники в виде текстов приложите, вместо картинок.

Comment: В таком случае вам придется сделать еще один поиск, который будет появляться в мобильной верстке а 1-ый скрываться, всё это решаемо через @медазапросы в css

Comment: Использовать скрипты в таком примере это костыль, вам всего лишь нудно сделать 2 блока под мобильную верстку и обычную и @медиазапросами скрывать один и показывать другой, в данном случае можете просто показывать и скрывать поле поиска

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev это скриншоты из официальной документации bootstrap. Незнаю, имеет ли смысл прикладывать суда еще и скопированный оттуда код :)

Comment: @RifmaMan то есть в бутсрапе "из коробки" нету готового решения? Если я хочу , например вообще изменить порядок каждого элемента, то мне только два блока делать?  Можете подсказать как это реализовать, или где про это почитать, я просто только начал разбираться в этой теме

Comment: Display flex - order?

Comment: @RomanAndreev меню использует адаптивную верстку, в которой элементы идут как бы по порядку слева направо, и при уменьшении разрешения экрана естественно они смещаются строго по порядку, в этом и смысл верстки, если же вы хотите перестроить порядок смещения, здесь уже придется прибегнуть к другим методам, из коробки такого нет да, но в бутстрапе есть условия, которыми вы можете попросту показывать другой блок с версткой и скрывать текущий, посмотрите по [этой ссылке](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

Comment: @RifmaMan спасибо, за помощь. Это мой первый вопрос тут, и что то я не могу найти соответствующей кнопки, типа спасибо или лайка :)

Comment: @RomanAndreev Выше этого текста вы видите комментарии, которые не считаются ответом, ответы внизу, комментарии пишут когда нет четкого ответа, а есть скажем подсказки, может кто-то позже даст ответ и тогда вы сможете решить, подошел ли он вам, либо если справились с задачей благодаря комментариям комьюнити вы можете просто закрыть вопрос.

Comment: @RifmaMan Окей понял! Прочитал то что по ссылке, и как скрывать элементы на определенных брейкпоинтах разобрался. Но как же всё таки их заменить на другие элементы(как вы говорили выше)?

Comment: @RomanAndreev Прошу прощения, но Responsive utilities для 4 альфа версии и в релизи они не работают, сейчас поищу куда их перенесли, а может и вообще отказались, что касается замены, я такой вариант не предлагал, логика была такова: разместить 2 формы поиска (или 2 меню) и при условии скрывать один и показывать другой через медиазапросы, но раньше это можно было решать через Responsive utilities от бутстрапа дописав просто класс к элементу.

Comment: @RomanAndreev, на сайте есть кое какие правила... И не плохо было бы их  соблюдать, Скриншоты в место живого кода не уместны...  Постарайся переформулировать вопрос и оформить надлежащим образом...

Comment: По ссылкам можно ознакомиться с правилами,   вот :  
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask      еще         
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions     и еще                     
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ваш готовый пример, всё решается с помощью [Display property](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 d-lg-none">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 d-none d-lg-block">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Внес правки, теперь всё должно корректно отрабатываться =)